# Can one say Shir Hamaalos without a Minyan?

Tags: tefilla, tehilim-psalms, aseres-yemei-teshuva

During the Aseres Yemei Teshuvah, many congregations say שיר המעלות after Yishtabach. Is there any problem saying שיר המעלות without a minyan?

Comment: Aside from the general issue of hefsek after Yishtabach, why might there be a problem without a minyan?

Comment: People do so while benching at least 3 times a week

Comment: @JoshK totally diff inyan, ones in the middle (hefsek) another a stam minhag (to have divrei Torah) Before benching